# How to edit the line appended into list multiple times?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Have a scenario where,

a. Previously the list was having one value only, so it was a straight away adding the line like given below.

```
s_array.append(' %s [%d:0] %s;'%(str(s_ud_in_cfg_array[i][1]), int(s_ud_l_var_temp[0]), str(s_ud_in_cfg_array[i][0]), ))
```

b. Have a scenario where a list has multiple values like

```
s_ud_l_var_tmp = ['32', '64', '16']
```

c. I wanted to add a line with the values from the array as given below into a list.

```
s_array.append(' %s [%d:0][%d:0][%d:0] %s;'%(str(s_ud_in_cfg_array[i][1]), int(s_ud_l_var_temp[0]), int(s_ud_l_var_temp[1]), int(s_ud_l_var_temp[2]), str(s_ud_in_cfg_array[i][0]), ))
```

c. But the catch here is the value in the s_ud_l_var_tmp can be keep varying and it won't be three all the times.

**UPDATE:**

a. Finally i got to two arrays as given below

```
value of le_temp_list ['%s', '[%s-1:0]', '[%d:0]', '%s']
value of le_temp_list_val ['logic', '`ADR_WTH', 31, 'green']
```

Where array le_temp_list has the list of %d's and %s's for which to be replaced values are in le_temp_list_val.

I wanted something like as given below, so that I can append the output of the below execution into an array.

```
'%s [%s-1:0] [%d:0] %s'%(logic, `ADR_WTH, 31, green)
```

So the final output should be like,

```
logic [`ADR_WTH-1:0] [31:0] green
```

i.e. expressions in le_temp_list is replaced by values in le_temp_list_val and represent the output.

Comment: If you generate the `[%d:0]` chain seperately your code will be much more dynamic, modular and readable.

Comment: @GalAbra: That's what I am trying it out. I tried adding the [%d:0] series into an array. But then I am confused on how to add the elements on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were trying to achieve?

```
s_ud_in_cfg_array = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
s_ud_l_var_temp = [1, 2, 3]
s_array = [];

for i in range(0, len(s_ud_in_cfg_array)):
    s_array.append(' %s [%d:0] %s;' % (str(s_ud_in_cfg_array[i][1]), int(s_ud_l_var_temp[0]), str(s_ud_in_cfg_array[i][0])))

print(s_array)

// output: [' b [1:0] a;', ' e [1:0] d;', ' h [1:0] g;']
```

Comment: Not this way. Have give more explicit examples in the UPDATE section above.